# How to put the of first and last element of Array in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have a dictionary like this

```
["Price": ["$00.00 - $200.00", "$200.00 - $400.00", "$600.00 - $800.00"]]
```

Now I am storing all the dictionary value in array like this

```
var priceRange: [String] = [String]()
if let obj = currentFilters["Price"] as? [String] {
        self.priceRange = obj
        printD(self.priceRange)
    }
```

And by the use of `Array.first` and `Array.last` method I will get the values of first element and last element of my array.

```
let first = priceRange.first ?? "" // will get("[$00.00 - $200.00]")
let last = priceRange.last ?? ""   // will get("[$600.00 - $800.00]")
```

But What I actually want is I want the **$00.00** from **first** and **$800** from **last** to make the desired combination of **[$00.00 - $800.00]**.

How can I do this. Please help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to take `first` value (`"$00.00 - $200.00"`), then `last` value (`"$600.00 - $800.00"`), then split them by "`-`" symbol and take first and last values respectively and combine it to single string.

```
let currentFilters = ["Price": ["$00.00 - $200.00", "$200.00 - $400.00", "$600.00 - $800.00"]]

var priceRange: [String] = [String]()
if let obj = currentFilters["Price"] as? [String] {
    priceRange = obj
    print(priceRange)
}

let first = priceRange.first!.split(separator: "-").first!
let last = priceRange.last!.split(separator: "-").last!

let range = "\(first) - \(last)"
```

For better optionals handling you can use this (**NB**, I'm following my over-descriptive coding style. This code can be much more compact)

```
func totalRange(filters: [String]?) -> String? {
    guard let filters = filters else { return nil }
    guard filters.isEmpty == false else { return nil }
    guard let startComponents = priceRange.first?.split(separator: "-"), startComponents.count == 2 else {
        fatalError("Unexpected Filter format for first filter") // or `return nil`
    }
    guard let endComponents = priceRange.last?.split(separator: "-"), endComponents.count == 2 else {
        fatalError("Unexpected Filter format for last filter") // or `return nil`
    }
    return "\(startComponents.first!) - \(endComponents.last!)"
}
let range = totalRange(filters: currentFilters["Price"])

let range1 = totalRange(filters: currentFilters["Not Exists"])
```

Past the code above to the playground. It can be written much shorter way, but I kept it like that for the sake of descriptivity

Comment: If your dictionary is empty, my code will crash your application :). It was made to demonstrate the way how you can achieve desired behaviour. Optional values handling is a subject of further implementation.

Comment: How can I handle this

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```
  let r = ["$00.00 - $200.00", "$200.00 - $400.00", "$600.00 - $800.00"]
          .reduce("", +) //Combine all strings
          .components(separatedBy: " - ") //Split the result
          .map({ String($0) }) //Convert from SubString to String
    print(r.first) //prints $00.00
    print(r.last) // prints $800.00

let newRange = [r.first!, r.last!].joined(separator: " - ")
```

Comment: but sir by use of these I will get 00.00 and 800.00 but i actually want [$00.00 - $800.00]

Comment: @wings just format the new string with first and last the way you want it.

Comment: Updated to your requirement @wings

Comment: @CZ54 Sir it is okay to use `!` in that code because sometimes I won't get the values

Comment: I'm assuming  you array is not empty, otherwise your range is `""`

Answer (score 2):

```
func priceRange(with priceRanges: [String]) -> String? {
    guard
        let min = priceRanges.first?.components(separatedBy: " - ").first,
        let max = priceRanges.last?.components(separatedBy: " - ").last else { return nil }

    return "[\(min) - \(max)]"
}

print(priceRange(
    with: [
        "$00.00 - $200.00",
        "$200.00 - $400.00",
        "$600.00 - $800.00"
    ]
))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split` to split up the range based on the `-` character than remove the whitespaces.

```
let first = priceRange.first?.split(separator: "-").first?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces) ?? ""
let last = priceRange.last?.split(separator: "-").last?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces) ?? ""
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let amountsArray = ["$00.00 - $200.00", "$200.00 - $400.00", "$600.00 - $800.00"]
let amounts = amountsArray.reduce("") { $0 + $1 }.split(separator: "-")
if let first = amounts.first, let last = amounts.last {
    print("[\(first)-\(last)]")
}
```

Comment: You get an extra " " when you split with "-".

Comment: You are right @RakeshaShastri. Thanks..!! I've updated the answer

Comment: Yes checked it but couldn't figure out where was wrong. It prints **$00.00 - $800.00**.

Comment: My bad. It's fine now. Although i should reming you that the OP wants it like this "[$00.00 - $800.00.]" So you might want to format your result.  :)

Comment: Updated the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this You can find your values:

```
if let obj = priceRange as? [String] {
    let max = priceRange.max()
    let min = priceRange.min()
    print(max?.components(separatedBy: " - ").map({$0.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)}).max())  //800
    print(min?.components(separatedBy: " - ").map({$0.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)}).min())   //00
}
```

Answer (score 0):

//use components(separatedBy:) :

let prices = f.components(separatedBy: " - ")

prices.first // $600.00

prices.last // $800.00

Answer (score 0):

You could also use String.components(separatedBy:):

```
var text = "100$ - 200$"
var new = text.components(separatedBy: " - ")[0]
print(new) // Prints 100$
```