# How to get the Lowest and Highest Value from Dictionary in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary, swift4

I am facing a problem in getting the values to make the desired combination. I am using a filter screen in my app. I asked this question to get the first and last element from the question [How to put the of first and last element of Array in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53151493/how-to-put-the-of-first-and-last-element-of-array-in-swift) and it is working but the problem is in my `FiterVC` first I selected the option `$400 - $600` and then I selected the `$200 - $400`. After selecting I am getting these values in my currentFilter variable.

```
private let menus = [

    ["title": "Price", "isMultiSelection": true, "values": [
        ["title": "$00.00 - $200.00"],
        ["title": "$200.00 - $400.00"],
        ["title": "$400.00 - $600.00"],
        ["title": "$600.00 - $800.00"],
        ["title": "$800.00 - $1000.00"],
        ]],
    ["title": "Product Rating", "isMultiSelection": true, "values": [
        ["title": "5"],
        ["title": "4"],
        ["title": "3"],
        ["title": "2"],
        ["title": "1"]
        ]],
    ["title": "Arriving", "isMultiSelection": true, "values": [
        ["title": "New Arrivials"],
        ["title": "Coming Soon"]
        ]]
]

private var currentFilters = [String:Any]()
```

Selecting values in `didSelect` method:-

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if tableView === self.menuTableView {
        self.currentSelectedMenu = indexPath.row
        self.menuTableView.reloadData()
        self.valueTableView.reloadData()
    }
    else {
        if let title = self.menus[self.currentSelectedMenu]["title"] as? String, let values = self.menus[self.currentSelectedMenu]["values"] as? [[String:Any]], let obj = values[indexPath.row]["title"] as? String {
            if let old = self.selectedFilters[title] as? [String], let isAllowedMulti = self.menus[self.currentSelectedMenu]["isMultiSelection"] as? Bool, !old.isEmpty, !isAllowedMulti {
                var temp = old
                if old.contains(obj), let index = old.index(of: obj) {
                    temp.remove(at: index)
                }
                else {
                    temp.append(obj)     
                }
                self.selectedFilters[title] = temp
            }
            else {
                self.selectedFilters[title] = [obj]
            }
            self.valueTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

And on Apply button click:-

```
@IBAction func applyButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.delegate?.didSelectedFilters(self, with: self.selectedFilters)
    printD(self.selectedFilters)
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

When I am printing the **selectedFilters** I am getting these values:-

```
currentFilters ["Price": ["$400.00 - $600.00", "$200.00 - $400.00"]]
```

And by using this method I am getting the first and last value from dictionary like this:-

```
if let obj = currentFilters["Price"] as? [String] {
   self.priceRange = obj
   printD(self.priceRange)

   let first = priceRange.first!.split(separator: "-").first!
   let last = priceRange.last!.split(separator: "-").last!
   let str = "\(first)-\(last)"
   let str2 = str.replacingOccurrences(of: "$", with: "", options: NSString.CompareOptions.literal, range: nil)
   newPrice = str2
   printD(newPrice)
}
```

The result is :-

```
400.00 - 400.00
```

but what I actually want is `200 - 600`. How can I do this. Please help?

[image]

Comment: Check if you are picking the correct item of the array once you split it by "-". Which items do you have in priceRange.first!.split(separator: "-") and priceRange.last!.split(separator: "-")?

Comment: you have `currentFilters ["Price": ["$400.00 - $600.00", "$200.00 - $400.00"]]` the output 400-400 is correct! You literally take the first (400) of the first range and the last of the last range (400)

Comment: @FedeHenze The solution will work if I first choose the `$200.00 - $400.00` and then I choose `$400.00 - $600.00` it will give `200 - 600` but if i do opposite then it won't work.

Comment: @inokey...Yes but what I want is `200 - 600`

Comment: @wings it doesn't work because you're not looking for the biggest value, you're looking for the first and the last element. These methods not aware of the values contained inside.

Comment: @wings why are you storing the selected filters in a dictionary? More importantly, why are they stored as `String`s!!!

Comment: @inokey.. yes sir it is

Comment: @RakeshaShastri... have to because I have other options to store like product ratinng and Arriving

Comment: How does that force you to store the range as a `String` in a dictionary?

Comment: @RakeshaShastri... What will be the better solution?

Comment: @wings Once you have the strings ranges save it as an Int in an array and then you can pick the lowest and highest value of each one.

Comment: In your current code you have assumed there will be two price ranges but there can be many check out my answer it will work for any number of price ranges

Comment: @Aakash...Yes Sir there will be many price ranges

Comment: @FedeHenze ... Sir that means I need to split every string first and change it into Int and then pick high and low value?

Comment: @wings i am writing an answer, check back in some time.

Comment: @wings check out the answer, I got for you.

Comment: Why don't you use a map table e.g. `0 = 0-200, 1 = 200-400` etc. ? The lower value is always `x * 200` and the upper value `x * 200 + 200`? That avoids the annoying extraction with `split` and `replaceOccurrences`

Comment: @vadian any answer Sir because I don't know how to use map table

Comment: @wings Did you try the answers below?

Comment: @Aakash... I am trying Sir

Comment: Assign tags (0-5) to the buttons. Declare `currentFilters` as  integer **array** `var currentFilters = [Int]()`. When a filter is selected/deselected add/remove the tag to/from the array. As mentioned the lower value is `tag * 200` and the higher value is `tag * 200 + 200`.

Comment: @vadian... Sir I can't declare it into `Int` because I am storing all the values in my `currentFilters` and the option Arriving has String values

Comment: You can. It's a question of the design. I just made a suggestion to improve a very cumbersome and inefficient design.

Comment: @vadian... Updated Sir Please check it

Answer (score 0):

However there are many solutions available to this problem but simplest and most relevant solution is highlighted here:

```
let min = 1000, max = 0
if let obj = currentFilters["Price"] as? [String] {
   self.priceRange = obj
   printD(self.priceRange)

   for str in obj{
     let first = str.split(separator: "-").first!.replacingOccurrences(of: "$", with: "", options:
            NSString.CompareOptions.literal, range: nil)
     let last = str.split(separator: "-").last!.replacingOccurrences(of: "$", with: "", options:
            NSString.CompareOptions.literal, range: nil)
     if Int(first) < min{
       min = first
     }
     if Int(last) > max{
       max = last
     }
   }
   let str = "\(min)-\(max)"
   newPrice = str
   printD(newPrice)
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. Your `min` is an `Int` by declaration, you complier will throw an error    at if statement line.

Comment: Prices are `Double`, not `Int`

Comment: @inokey : cast it to Double type instead

Answer (score -1):

You can use an enum with functions to load your prices ranges instead of using directly Strings.

```
enum PriceRange: String {
    case
    low     = "200 - 400",
    high    = "400 - 600"

    static let priceRanges = [low, high]

    func getStringValue() -> String {
        return self.rawValue
    }

    func getMinValueForRange(stringRange: String) -> Int? {
        switch stringRange {
        case "200 - 400":
            return 200;

        case "400 - 600":
            return 400;
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }

    func getMaxValueForRange(stringRange: String) -> Int? {
        switch stringRange {
        case "200 - 400":
            return 400;

        case "400 - 600":
            return 600;
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }

}
```

Then you can use/add functions to get the result that you are looking for.

Comment: Price ranges will be dynamic and may not be multiple of 200

Answer (score -2):

Here's the small solution of your problem. It all breaks down to that: you get all the values from your filters, and then iterating over getting all the values from it. That way you avoid comparing the pairs and instead comparing the exact values.

```
let currentFilters =  ["Price": ["$400.00 - $600.00", "$200.00 - $400.00"]]
let ranges = currentFilters["Price"]!
var values: [Double] = []
ranges.forEach { range in // iterate over each range
    let rangeValues = range.split(separator: "-")
    for value in rangeValues { // iterate over each value in range
        values.append(Double( // cast string value to Double
            String(value)
                .replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
                .replacingOccurrences(of: "$", with: "")
        )!)
    }
}

let min = values.min() // prints 200
let max = values.max() // prints 600
```

Comment: it won't work, by comparing string value means $1000.00 will be smaller than $400.00.

Comment: @inokey pls don't force unwrap this cause crashes in some situations

Answer (score -3):

We can do by steps -

1 - Get the price ranges from the dictionary

2 - Iterate over those price ranges

3 - Split the range by "-" and check if the prices count is 2 else this is an invalid price range

4 - Get the numeric components from the two prices and then compare from the previously saved min and max values and update them accordingly

Try this -

```
if let priceRanges = currentFilters["Price"] as? [String] { // Extract the price ranges from dictionary

    var minValue: Double? // Holds the min value
    var maxValue: Double? // Holds the max value

    for priceRange in priceRanges { Iterate over the price ranges

        let prices = priceRange.split(separator: "-") // Separate price range by "-"

        guard prices.count == 2 else { // Checks if there are 2 prices else price range is invalid
            print("invalid price range")
            continue // skip this price range when invalid
        }

        let firstPrice = String(prices[0]).numericString // Extract numerics from the first price
        let secondPrice = String(prices[1]).numericString // Same for the second price

        if let value = Double(firstPrice) { // Check if the price is valid amount by casting it to double
            if let mValue = minValue { // Check if we have earlier saved a minValue from a price range
                minValue = min(mValue, value) // Assign minimum of current price and earlier save min price
            } else {
                minValue = value // Else just save this price to minValue
            }
        }

        if let value = Double(secondPrice) { // Check if the price is valid amount by casting it to double
            if let mValue = maxValue { // Check if we have earlier saved a maxValue from a price range
                maxValue = max(mValue, value) // Assign maximum of current price and earlier save max price
            } else {
                maxValue = value // Else just save this price to maxValue
            }
        }
    }
    if let minV = minValue, let maxV = maxValue { // Check if we have a min and max value from the price ranges
        print("\(minV) - \(maxV)")
    } else {
        print("unable to find desired price range") // Else print this error message
    }
}

extension String {

    /// Returns a string with all non-numeric characters removed
    public var numericString: String {
        let characterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "01234567890.").inverted
        return components(separatedBy: characterSet)
            .joined()
    }
}
```

Comment: Sir explain your answer please

Comment: @wings I have updated the answer, let me know in case you need more info

Comment: Okay I will check it now